# Get sum() of all rows with a given month

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this table here:

| Purchase date | Price (USD) |
| --- | --- |
| 29.12.2021 | 2000 |
| 04.01.2022 | 2300 |
| 05.01.2022 | 1500 |
| 07.05.2022 | 3800 |
| 15.09.2022 | 1500 |

I need a formula that summarizes all prices in a given month. So for January it should give me 3800. I suspect that sumif() must be used, but I don't know what criteria to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can achieve it: you can use formulas, pivot table, even power query.

Assuming the dates are in column A and the prices on column B, below are two formulae that you can use (there are more).

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH($A$2:$A$6)=D7,$B$2:$B$6,0))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$2:$A$6)=D7)*$B$2:$B$6)
```